# counif(something) the column A is not empty in tableau

Tags: sql, tableau-api

How to make an expression in tableau that if the field is not empty then count another field?

Something like *count if(something) the column A is not empty*.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to count all rows.  If so, use: `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`.

Otherwise, use `COALESCE()` or `CASE`.  If "empty" means `NULL`, then:

```
COUNT(COALESCE(a, b))
```

If "empty" means something else, then something like:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN a <> '' THEN a ELSE b END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention that condition in where clause columnA is not null or <>''

```
select count(something_column) from your_table where columnA <>'' or columnA is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tableau calculation is `ifnull([First Field], [Second Field])`